# Find the highest and lowest possible value of function $f(x)={3x^2+6x+6\over x^2+4x+5}$

Tags: functions

> Find the highest and lowest value of the next function **without the use of derivatives**
>   $$f(x)={3x^2+6x+6\over x^2+4x+5}$$

Okay so my teacher gave me this problem, and told me to strictly solve it **without using derivatives**. Obviously with using derivatives it's pretty easy, just find where $f'(x_0)=0$, and check it's second derivative in $x_0$ to see if it's a maximum or minimum.

So I was thinking about this:

Since this function is written as a fraction, the lowest possible value should be when the numerator value is the lowest, while the denominator is the highest possible value.

**BUT**, again to find the highest and lowest value of both I could use derivatives again, which again isn't the point.

I can see that both the numerator and denominator of this fraction is always positive for every $x$, so maybe there's a hint that I can't see there?

Maybe I could use limits too, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $\kappa$ belongs to the range of $f$, it follows that
$$3x^2+6x+6 = \kappa(x^2+4x+5)$$
has a real solution, hence the discriminant of
$$ (3-\kappa)x^2+(6-4\kappa)x+(6-5\kappa) $$
i.e. $-4\kappa^2+36\kappa-36$, is non-negative. It follows that the extreme values of $f$ are given by the roots of $-4\kappa^2+36\kappa-36$, i.e. $\color{red}{\frac{3}{2}\left(3\pm\sqrt{5}\right)}$.

<sup>I believe this (exploiting discriminants) was the ancient method for the determination of the stationary values of rational functions, before the *Method of Fluxions*. But relics have their elegance!</sup>

Comment: @Chickenmancer: the roots of the polynomial in $\kappa$ are the same, so why to waste time in performing useless simplifications?

Comment: @Chickenmancer: oh, sorry, I see. There was a typo, now fixed.

Comment: Okay, so I got everything you said and I see it's correct, but could you clear up how do we know that finding the roots of $-4k^2+36k-36$ gives the extreme values?

Comment: @Aleksa: for $\kappa$ larger than $\frac{3}{2}(3+\sqrt{5})$ or smaller than $\frac{3}{2}(3-\sqrt{5})$ the equation $f(x)=\kappa$ has no real solution, so...

Comment: Oh got it, pretty obvious, thanks!

Comment: I agree that the use of discriminants here is elegant!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

One can cast this issue into an eigenvalue problem.

I recognize that, evidently, this involves much more computation than the straightforward method given by @Jack D'Aurizio, but see remarks at the bottom.

Moreover, I understand that probably, you, the OP, haven't already seen these notions, but, who knows...

Let us define $A=\begin{pmatrix}3&3\\3&6\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&5\end{pmatrix}$.

Let $B=CC^T$ be the Cholesky factorization of $B$, with

$$C= \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Let $D:=C^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$

Then the extreme values are the eigenvalues $\frac32(3\pm \sqrt{5})$ of

$$M:=D^TAD=\begin{pmatrix} 3&-3\\
    -3&6\end{pmatrix}.$$

Explanation : setting $x=\frac{s}{t}$ in the given fraction transforms it into the quotient of 2 quadratic forms :

$$\frac{3x^2+6x+6}{x^2+4x+5}=\frac{3s^2+6st+6t^2}{s^2+4st+5t^2}=\frac{X^TAX}{X^TBX} \ \  with \ X:=\binom{y}{t}\tag{1}$$

(with matrices $A$ and $B$ defined upwards).

Then transform (1) into the following Rayleigh quotient :

$$\frac{(CX)^T(D^TAD)(CX)}{(CX)^T(CX)} = \frac{U^T M U}{U^TU}$$

which is known to take all its values in  $[\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max}]$.

Remark : A natural question is : what is the information brought by eigenvectors $U_1=\binom{s}{t}=\binom{-0.8507}{-0.5257}$ and $U_2=\binom{s}{t}=\binom{-0.5257}{0.8507}$. Using 
$X_1=C^{-1}U_1=\binom{0.2008}{-0.5257}$ and $X_2=C^{-1}U_2=\binom{ -2.2270}{0.8507}$, the reader will easily see that they provide information about the abscissas $x=\frac{s'}{t'}=\frac{0.2008}{-0.5257}=-0.3820$ and $x=\frac{-2.2270}{0.8507}=-2.6178$ of points where the minimum and the maximum occur.

Remarks : The advantage of this method lies on the methodological side :

- most people working in applied mathematics will appreciate to have a method handling eigenvalues instead of specific numbers for which one has to rediscover properties, like sensibility to variations.
- it can be extended to as many variables as desired, like finding the min and max values of $$\frac{3x^2+5y^2+6z^2-2xz+3yz}{x^2+2y^2+3z^2-2xz}.$$ (for any $x,y,z$).

Comment: I enjoyed your use of quadratic forms!

Comment: @Chickenmancer  If you want to see another nice application of Linear Algebra, take a look at the following recent question and its answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3029158