# Is there any strategy to win this color filling game?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, game-theory

- As shown in the image, firstly, the player will get a square filled up with $n\times n$ boxes ($n\geq 3$).
- Once the player click on any of the boxes, the color of it and boxes next to it (up, down, left, right) will change (blue to white/white to blue).
- The goal is to fill up the whole square with blue.

Screenshot:

[image]

And here is the javascript version of the game:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5">

<script>
function ShowMenu(bMenu) {
document.all.idFinder.style.display = (bMenu) ? "none" : "block"
document.all.idMenu.style.display = (bMenu) ? "block" : "none"
idML.className = (bMenu) ? "cOn" : "cOff"
idRL.className = (bMenu) ? "cOff" : "cOn"
return false
}
</script>
<style>
A.cOn {text-decoration:none;font-weight:bolder}
#article {font: 12pt Verdana, geneva, arial, sans-serif;  background: white; color: black; padding: 10pt 15pt 0 5pt}
#article P.start {text-indent: 0pt}
#article P {margin-top:0pt;font-size:10pt;text-indent:12pt}
#article #author {margin-bottom:5pt;text-indent:0pt;font-style: italic}
#pageList P {padding-top:10pt}
#article H3 {font-weight:bold}
#article DL, UL, OL {font-size: 10pt}
</style>
<script>
function addList(url,desc) {
if ((navigator.appName=="Netscape") || (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)>=4)) {
var w=window.open("","_IDHTML_LIST_","top=0,left=0,width=475,height=150,history=no,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=no")
var d=w.document
if (!w._init) {
d.open()
d.write("<TITLE>Loading...</TITLE><EM>Loading...</EM>")
d.close()
d.location.replace("/assist/listing.asp?url="+escape(url)+"&desc="+escape(desc))
w.opener=self
window.status="Personal Assistant (Adding): " + desc
} else {
window.status=w.addOption(url,desc)
w.focus()
}
}
else
alert("Your browser does not support the personal assistant.")
return false
}
</script>
<style>
    #board {cursor: default}
    #board TD {width: 25px; height: 25px; }
  </style>
<script>
    var size=10
    var moves = 0
    var off = size*2
    var on = 0
    var current = null
    function doOver() {
      if ((event.srcElement.tagName=="TD") && (current!=event.srcElement)) {
        if (current!=null)
          current.style.backgroundColor = current._background
        event.srcElement._background = event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor
        event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey"
        current = event.srcElement
      }
    }

    function setColor(el) {
      if ((el._background=="") || (el._background==null)) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
        el._background = "blue"
      } else {
        el.style.backgroundColor = ""
        el._background = ""
      }
    }

    function countLights() {
      off = 0; on = 0
      for (var x=0; x < size; x++)
        for (var y=0; y < size; y++) {
          var p = board.rows[x].cells[y]
          if (p._background=="blue")
            on++
          else
            off ++
        }
        document.all.on.innerText = on
      if (off!=0)
        document.all.off.innerText = off
      else
        document.all.off.innerText = "You Win!"
      return (off==0)
    }

    function doClick() {
      setColor(current)
      var cellIdx = current.cellIndex
      var rowIdx = current.parentElement.rowIndex
      if (rowIdx>0)
        setColor(board.rows[rowIdx-1].cells[cellIdx])
      if (rowIdx<size-1)
        setColor(board.rows[rowIdx+1].cells[cellIdx])
      if (cellIdx>0)
        setColor(board.rows[rowIdx].cells[cellIdx-1])
      if (cellIdx<size-1)
        setColor(board.rows[rowIdx].cells[cellIdx+1])
      moves++
      document.all.moves.innerText = moves
      win = countLights()
      if (win) {
        board.onclick = null
        board.onmouseover = null
        current.style.background = "blue"
      }
    }

    function buildBoard() {
      var str = "<TABLE ID=board ONSELECTSTART=\"return false\" ONCLICK=\"doClick()\" ONMOUSEOVER=\"doOver()\" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=5>"
      for (var x=0; x < size; x++) {
        str+="<TR>"
        for (var y=0; y < size; y++) {
          str+="<TD> </TD>"
        }
        str+="</TR>"
      }
      str+="</TABLE>"
      return str
    }

    function newGame() {
      size = document.all.gameSize.value
      if (size<3)
        size=3
      if (size>15)
        size=15
      document.all.gameSize.value = size
      document.all.board.outerHTML = buildBoard()
      moves=0
      document.all.moves.innerText = moves
      countLights()

    }

  </script>
  <p align="center"><big><font color="#0000FF">Click on the boxes, can you make them all become blue?</font><strong><font
color="#FF0000"><big><big></big></big></font></strong></big></p>

<p align="center"><font color="#0000FF">Let's try!</font></p>

<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><div align="right"><table ID="score" border="0" width="284">
      <tr>
        <td width="52">Moves: </td>
        <td id="moves" width="33">0</td>
        <td width="42">Whites:</td>
        <td id="off" width="36">25</td>
        <td width="46">Blues:</td>
        <td id="on" width="39">0</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div></td>
    <td width="50%"><div align="left"><table width="204">
      <tr>
        <td width="54">Size: </td>
        <td width="41"><input ID="gameSize" TYPE="text" VALUE="10" SIZE="2"></td>
        <td width="97"><input ONCLICK="newGame()" TYPE="button" VALUE="Start"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p align="center"><script>
    document.write(buildBoard())
  </script></p>
```

Comment: Can the second player just repeat the first players move, guaranteeing a draw?

Comment: there was a (old) game named poly-off with square or hexagon as a starting area, and different filling patterns to try, this one being one of the patterns. I played it many times, but the strategy is not easy to describe. basically you start from a corner and spread and then deal with remaining blanks in the opposite corner.

Comment: This looks similar to "Lights out" game, there are some strategies described for solving those puzzles, for example, here: https://www.logicgamesonline.com/lightsout/tutorial.html

Comment: I have added the tag [linear-algebra] because the question here is as follows: represent the whole board as a vector in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Clicking on any cell adds a fixed vector in $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^{n^2}$. The question is whether the "all ones" vector is a linear combination of those $n^2$ vectors. Which will certainly be the case if they are linearly independent.

Comment: About strategies for solving questions dealing with "Lights out" (equivalent) games, see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3029122/305862)

Comment: [This](https://www.logicgamesonline.com/lightsout/tutorial.html) may provide the answer...

Comment: @Jonah I think there is only one player. It's more like a puzzle than a game.