# How to solve this problem with Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, recreational-mathematics

I have a $N \times N$ grid, each cell initialized with an integer between $0$ and $5$.
If I select one cell, each adjacent cell (8 cells if not on an edge or a corner) - but not the selected one- are incremented by $1$ then taken $\text{mod } 5$.
I need to find the cells to select to get from the initial state to a given targeted state.
I assume there is always a solution but I don't know if it is unique.

I have done this heuristically, but my implementation is very inefficient, and I wondered if linear algebra could be used here. In case it can be done with LA, any leads to help me formulate the problems would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: "Incremented by $1\% 5$", what does this mean?

Comment: I believe they mean increment by 1 then take mod 5 of the number after that.

Comment: Are there 4 adjacent cells (L, R, T, B) in the interior, 3 on an edge and 2 at a corner; or are diagonal cells adjacent, so 8 to an interior cell, 5 on an edge and 3 at a corner? Either way, is it obvious that you can always go between two such grids with this algorithm or that the process is unique? Is there any background to this problem?

Comment: @PavanC. thank you for the edition, it is correct we add 1 and then we apply module 5

Comment: @Paul it is indeed 8 adjacent cells except if on a side or in a corner (I will edit for clarity). I have no guarantee there is always a solution (but I assume it is the case) or a unique path to get there,

Comment: It's a variation of [Lights Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)), but mod 5 instead of 2 and a different pattern of neighbours. Similar solving methods apply here. For any particular $N$ you can set up a matrix and invert it mod 5 (as far as possible), and use that to solve any pattern. However there is probably no general strategy that works for every board size $N$ - each board size has its own strategy given by that inverted $N^2\times N^2$ matrix.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis Yes and questions have already been asked for this game, for example this one : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3027931/305862

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

Let us consider the case $3\times 3$. Define $9$ matrices according to
$$
\Delta_{1,1}=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1&0 \\ 1&1&0 \\ 0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\Delta_{1,2}=\begin{pmatrix}1& 0&1 \\ 1&1&1 \\ 0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\Delta_{1,3}=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1&0 \\ 0&1&1 \\ 0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\Delta_{2,1}=\begin{pmatrix}1& 1&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\Delta_{2,2}=\begin{pmatrix}1& 1&1 \\ 1&0&1 \\ 1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}\\
\Delta_{2,3}=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1&1 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}\\
\Delta_{3,1}=\begin{pmatrix}0& 0&0 \\ 1&1&0 \\ 0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\Delta_{3,2}=\begin{pmatrix}0& 0&0 \\ 1&1&1 \\ 1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\\
\Delta_{3,3}=\begin{pmatrix}0& 0&0 \\ 0&1&1 \\ 0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Let us record the state into a $3\times 3$ matrix (with entries in $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$), let the initial state be $I$.
Then, any reachable state $F$ is of the form
$$
F=I+\sum_{i,j=1}^3n_{i,j}\Delta_{i,j}.
$$
Introduce the linear transformation $\mathscr L$ of $Mat(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z,3\times 3)$ onto itself by
$$
N\mapsto \sum_{i,j=1}^3n_{i,j}\Delta_{i,j}.
$$
Ordering the entries of $N$ as a $9$-dimensional vector $(n_{11},n_{12},n_{13},n_{21},n_{22},n_{23},n_{31},n_{32},n_{33})$, $\mathscr L$ is represented by the matrix
$$
L=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
It can be checked that $\det L=0$, hence there are initial and final state which cannot be joined by this process.

For $1\times 1$ and $2\times 2$ the corresponding linear transformation $\mathscr L$ is instead invertible. Probably with some work (and/or some smart ideas) one can understand for which $n$ the relevant matrix $L$ is invertible.

EDIT: in fact, for the case $3\times 3$, the non-invertibility comes from the fact that the matrices $\Delta_{i,j}$ are not l.i.:
$$
\Delta_{1,1}-\Delta_{1,3}-\Delta_{3,1}+\Delta_{3,3}=0_{3\times 3}.
$$
A similar phenomenon occurs in the $4\times 4$ case:
$$
\Delta_{1,1}+\Delta_{1,4}
+\Delta_{2,1}-\Delta_{2,2}-\Delta_{2,3}+\Delta_{2,4}
+\Delta_{3,1}-\Delta_{3,2}-\Delta_{3,3}+\Delta_{3,4}
+\Delta_{1,4}+\Delta_{4,4}=0_{4\times 4}
$$
and it is likely to occur for higher $n$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your inputs.
Thanks to @Jaap I was directed to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)) on LightOut and there I found a link to a [detailed article](https://www.xarg.org/2018/07/lightsout-solution-using-linear-algebra/) giving all the required steps. I share it as it might be useful to others.
Also, the implementation in python was made easy thanks to the open source library [galois](https://mhostetter.github.io/galois/latest/).

I will accept the answer of @Giulio for the quality of his post !

Answer (score 0):

The way I would translate this into linear algebra is to consider the set $A_{i,j} \subset M_N(\mathbb{F}_5)$ where each matrix $A_{i,j}$ is filled whith $0$ in all entries except those surrounding the $i,j$ entry. Then the existence of a solution that gets you from the initial state to any given one is equivalent to $A_{i,j}$ being an spanning set of $M_N(\mathbb{F}_5)$, the uniqueness of a solution would be equivalent to it being a linearly independent set. As $dim(M_N(\mathbb{F}_5))=N^2$, the size of the set $A_{i,j}$, being a spannning set is equivalent to being linearly independet.